# Adding several coloumns in one alter

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

```
ALTER TABLE 'S_DET' ADD(
'SCHETION' VARCHAR(1) ,
'FDATE'     DATETIME    ,
'TDATE' DATETIME    ,
'SCTIME'    VARCHAR(8)  ,
'SCTYPE'            VARCHAR(10),
'PERY'              VARCHAR(10),
'P_NB'  NUMERIC(2)  ,
'LAST_P_DATE'   DATETIME            )
GO
```

I received an email contaning the folowing query.
I know we can apply that in oracle but I dont think we can apply it on sybase because I had an error

> incorrect syntax near the keyword add

IF its incorrect, is there a similar way where I can add several columns at the same time ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should remove parenthesis, apostrophes and add `null` or `not null`

```
ALTER TABLE S_DET 
ADD SCHETION VARCHAR(1) null,
    FDATE    DATETIME    null,
    TDATE    DATETIME    null,
    SCTIME   VARCHAR(8)  null,
    SCTYPE   VARCHAR(10) null,
    PERY     VARCHAR(10) null,
    P_NB     NUMERIC(2)  null,
    LAST_P_DATE   DATETIME  null           
GO
```